# manipulate DOM after Blaze is done with rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, materialize

In my meteor application I want to preload a select option list with values from my collection.

In my template I tried this, which works:

```
{{#each items}}
    <p>
        {{value}}
        {{title}}
    </p>
{{/each}}
```

The above code represents just an pre stage version of the actual code.
Then, I tried this:

```
<select id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Bitte wählen</option>
    {{#each items}}
      <option value="{{value}}" disabled selected>{{title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Unfortunately, it won't fill the list with any data.

I'm using materialize as UI framework, and what materialize would do is rendering the `select option` as a `ul li` unordered list instead of rendering the `select option` to make the user able to choose between the values. The select option list has to be initialized as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();   
});
```

Apparantely, `$(document).ready()` will be fired before blaze is done with rendering the contents. How can I force the material initialization to be run just after blaze is done adding the options to the select list?

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking is the [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) method

```
Template. category.onRendered(function(){
  //manipulate DOM here
});
```

Sometimes you will need to use a timeout like this.

```
Template. category.onRendered(function(){
      Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
        //Manipulate DOM here
        // this is most like a hack but it works some of the cases 
      },0);
    });
```